# How to partition the table, week-wise?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a table with hundreds of thousands of records. How to partition the table, week-wise?

A few million rows insertion will be taking place in my table in a day.So i need to partition it weekly. There is a datetime column which I want to partition by weekly

Comment: What is your table definition?  Primary key, other indexes, typical queries, expected workload (read/write)?

Answer (score 1):

First of all what kind of database are you using? And are you referring to table partitioning?

Anyways for Oracle, please see this link..

https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=879608

I'm not too sure about how this would be done in PostgreSQL, but I think partitioning is much less relevant for PostgreSQL rather than for Oracle

Comment: nice answer. i've done this in informix as well.

Comment: Note the "mysql" tag for the question. Good answer though!

Comment: yeah i just noticed the mysql tag, sorry about that lol

Answer (score 1):

For mysql, i think you can use this as a reference:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8854095/mysql-partitioning-by-year-and-week

for informix, interval partitioning is available as I have had experience with this.